# getting a nonexistent k8s resource in argo workflow

Tags: argo-workflows, argo

I want to get a non-exists resource using argo workflow, I use the native resource template, I use the following code

````
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: minimal-test-case
  namespace: argo-workflows
spec:
  entrypoint: workflow
  templates:
  - name: workflow
    steps:
    - - name: check-for-existence
        template: check-for-existence
  - name: check-for-existence
    resource:
      action: get
      manifest: |
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        metadata:
          name: does-not-exist
          namespace: argo-workflows
    outputs:
      parameters:
      - name: not-found
        valueFrom:
          jsonPath: '{.metadata.name}'```

this would report error, is there workaround to pass this?
````

Comment: Error from server (NotFound):  not found